How to create an autonumbering formula based on three columns
I'm trying to create a formula that will automatically generate a numeric code for each combination of columns. The first column is populated by a dropdown list, so that's an easy if-then formula (make in the attached image). The hard part is assigning column B a value that restarts when there is a new "make", and yet assigns the same value if that make is already entered. And then tougher yet is to assign a colour code that also restarts when there is a new model.
So, in the image provided, in column A, users pick their make. Honda will auto populate "1." into column D. Then the user enters the make into column B. Row 2 will add "1." into the code for the first entry (Accord), "2." for the second entry, etc. But if one of those models gets entered again in a lower row, the code will remember what was already assigned.
Same idea for column D.
I can't make only drop-down lists for the model and colour column - users need to be able to enter custom values (it's not for make-model-colour - I'm just using that as an example to show what I need).
I've tried using countif and if-then statements using arrays, but it's not working. Any solutions would be greatly appreciated.
Image of Table

Markdown



Name
Model
Colour




Honda
Accord
Black


Honda
Civic
Red


Toyota
Rav4
Silver


Honda
Accord
Blue


Ford
F-150
Onyx


Ford
F-150
White


Chevrolet
Silverado
Moonlight


Ford
F-150
Steel


Chevrolet
Silverado
Pearl


Audi
Q4
Midnight


Audi
Q4
Chrome


Audi
Q8
Night


Audi
Q4
Gunmetal




please see How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example and read How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users? and don't forget to read Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question? . Also check out the tour, and help center

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Let try this formula: The formula is in cell D2 and drag (copy) down.
=MATCH(A2,UNIQUE(A$2:A2),0)&"."&MATCH(B2,UNIQUE(FILTER(B$2:B2,A2=A$2:A2)),0)&"."&MATCH(C2,UNIQUE(FILTER($C$2:$C2,A$2:A2&B$2:B2=A2&B2)),0)


